# Untyped decimal literals

Tags: types, casting, floating-point, d

Using this code:

```c
import std.conv, std.stdio;

void main() {
   auto s = "2.9";
   auto n = s.to!(float);
   auto n2 = s.to!(double);
   auto n3 = s.to!(real);
   [n == 2.9, n2 == 2.9, n3 == 2.9].writeln;
}
```

I get this result:

```
[false, false, false]
```

Huh? If a literal `2.9` is not a `float`, `double` or `real`, what is it?

Comment: [I get `[false, true, true]`.](https://ideone.com/LbuHyF)

Comment: Also, quoting the [docs](https://dlang.org/spec/lex.html#floatliteral), "Floating literals with no suffix are of type double."

Comment: A good, related, read: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/ - it is C++ but it is on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At run.dlang.io, I'm seeing `[false, true, true]`.

This may give you a hint as to why you're getting the results you see:

```
writefln("%a", n);
writefln("%a", n2);
writefln("%a", n3);
writefln("%a", 2.9);
```

Due to how floating point values are stored, you can't rely on `==` when you've done any sort of transformation on them. In this case, since the values are parsed from a string, you aren't seeing the precise bit pattern that matches the literal `2.9`. Contrast that with the below code, which should result in an array of `true` values:

```
auto n = 2.9;
auto n2 = 2.9;
auto n3 = 2.9;
[n == 2.9, n2 == 2.9, n3 == 2.9].writeln;
```

So in your case, you probably [should use std.math.approxEqual](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_math.html#.approxEqual):

```
[approxEqual(n, 2.9), approxEqual(n2, 2.9), approxEqual(n3, 2.9)].writeln;
```

I also recommend Don Clugston's DConf 2016 talk, [Using Floating Point Without Losing Your Sanity](https://youtu.be/YEUAUnamQiA).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add `f` to the literal like this:

```c
import std.conv, std.stdio;

void main() {
   auto s = "9.9";
   auto n = s.to!(float);
   writeln(n == 9.9f);
}
```

Comment: I do not see this as always working.  "9.9" -> rounds to the nearest `double` and then `s.to!(float)` rounds that to the nearest `float`.  This is rounding [twice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) and once in a while will differ from `9.9f` which rounds the text directly to a `float` depending on if 9.9, 1.23, 4.2, etc was used.   Maybe about 1 in a billion non-representable constants will have this trouble.